# Combining / Nesting Sequential API Requests In Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch, httprequest, sequential

I'm creating an asynchronous function as a method within a Vue instance, which I will invoke once the component has mounted.

**What I need to do**

After the resolution of a first API request (getDevicesInOrganization), I need to iterate over the array of results from this response, and make more API requests (getDeviceVariableData) using a value passed in as an argument from each result(from first requests response). Then push the value I get back from each response of each `getDeviceVariableData` API request to an array.

**What I've tried**

I create a single async function called (called getOfflineListData) that will house the other requests (and get invoked when the component is mounted). Inside `getOfflineListData` the `getDevicesInOrganization` request is invoked, and I try to make the additional requests by iterating over the response, but I get an array of undefined values.

```
    getOfflineListData: function () {
      this.getDevicesInOrganization().then((data) => {
        data.results.forEach((result) => {
          this.names = result.name
          this.ids = result.id

          this.deviceRequestPromises.push(
            this.getDeviceVariableData(result.label),
          )
        })
        Promise.all(this.deviceRequestPromises).then((data) => {
          console.log(data)
        })
      })
    },
```

Comment: `await promise.then....` always a bad sign. Use async/await OR promise.then ... not both ...

Comment: The await statement looks useless here as there is no code running after the assignation. What looks weird to me is that you are expecting to store the json in your constant when you could just do .then(res => res.json()).then(json => {json.results...etc})

Comment: I think the issue may be in your `getDeviceVariableData` function. Since the code you have posted above should work.

Comment: organizationDevices  wouldn't have any results in that .then ... surprised your code runs. Haven't thought to hard about it though

Comment: @JaromandaX I switched to just using promise.then thanks for your help!

Comment: @WillD I edited my getDeviceVariableData function and everything works now. Thanks a ton!!